# MS Word r/w in python, Python-docx issue and win32com references?

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

Recently I'am experimenting with different API's for MS Word file management (writing for now). At this point I need just a simple writing python API. I tried win32com module which prove to be very robust with lack of examples for python online (very little knowledge of VB and C to be able to translate examples from MSDN).

I tried to use python-docx but after install I am getting this traceback for any docx function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\filepath.py", line 9, in <module>
    ispit = newdocument()
NameError: name 'newdocument' is not defined
```

I had some problems with installation of lxml by source and by easy_install. It was checking for libxlm2 and libxslt binaries. I downloaded them and added environmental paths but the installation trough source or easy_install stopped every time.

Finally I used unofficial python extension package from this site [Link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). 
Installation was fast and there was no errors in the end.

Is there something I can do to make docx work and is there some python win32com related references online? I couldn't find any. (except [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/)(VB not python) and [O'Reily's Python programming on win32](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565926219.do))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using `win32com`, bear in mind that you are talking to the Word object model. You don't need to know a lot of VBA or other languages to apply the samples to using Python; you just need to figure out which parts of the object model are being used.

Let's take the following sample (in VBA) which will create a new instance of the `Application`, and load a new document into that new instance:

```vb
Public Sub NewWordApp()

    'Create variables to reference objects
    '(This line is not needed in Python; you don't need to declare variables 
    'or their types before using them)
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application, wordDoc As Word.Document

    'Create a new instance of a Word Application object
    '(Another difference - in VBA you use Set for objects and simple assignment for 
    'primitive values. In Python, you use simple assignment for objects as well.)
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application

    'Show the application
    wordApp.Visible = True

    'Create a new document in the application
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

    'Set the text of the first paragraph
    '(A Paragraph object doesn't have a Text property. Instead, it has a Range property
    'which refers to a Range object, which does have a Text property.)
    wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Hello, World!"

End Sub
```

A similar snippet of code in Python might look like this:

```
import win32com.client

#Create an instance of Word.Application
wordApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

#Show the application
wordApp.Visible = True

#Create a new document in the application
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

#Set the text of the first paragraph
wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Hello, World!"
```

Some links to the Word object model:

- [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838565%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object
- [Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840891%28v=office.14%29.aspx) collection
- [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff822963%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object
- [Paragraphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837506%28v=office.14%29.aspx) collection
- [Paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845307%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object
- [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845882%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object
- [Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff192359%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Some Python examples:

- [Python and Microsoft Office – Using PyWin32](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/)
- [Use Python to parse Microsoft Word documents using PyWin32 Library](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/09/use-python-to-parse-microsoft-word-documents-using-pywin32-library/)

Comment: Best source yet! Thank you!