# Updating MS Word Document w/ VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a Word 2013 document (.docx) with values I need replacing.  I can find plenty of code but can't get it to work as the imports word.application doesn't work.

My form has a text box to specify the filename of the word document and a text box for the user to put a value into (tbCRMID).  Once I execute I need the value in the word document ( to be replaced with tbCRMID.text).

I have a host of other replacements to do but once I get one working, I should be all set.

Here is my code:

```
Try 
    Dim NewOutputFile As String 
    Dim newApp As Object 
    Dim newDoc As Object 
    newApp = CreateObject("Word.Applicatoin") 
    newApp.visible = True 
Catch ex As Exception 
    MsgBox(ex.Message) 
End Try
```

This code generates the error `"Cannot create Active X control"`.

Comment: The following code produces an error about "Cannot create Active X control".  Trying to open the program successfully, then I'll add the document to open and then work the the find/replace functions.  

Try
  Dim NewOutputFile As String
  Dim newApp As Object
  Dim newDoc As Object
  newApp = CreateObject("Word.Applicatoin")
  newApp.visible = True

Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

Comment: Put your code in the question above - edit it. Then you can format the code block.

Comment: @GeorgeVaisey - How did you add the reference for the `Microsoft Word` library?

Comment: @KarlAnderson The OP wouldn't need to add a reference to Word; he's using `CreateObject`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - what? the OP needs a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library, just like you said in your answer!

Comment: @KarlAnderson [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/z4393zyz(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx) is a VB.NET function for creating ActiveX objects. You don't need to know anything about the type of object you are creating (nor do you need a reference to its library), as `CreateObject` returns an `Object`, but you can still call members on the object because of late-bound object behavior in VB.NET.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - I understand, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled `Word.Application`. Also, consider adding a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library, and then you can use strong types and intellisense:

```
Dim newApp As New Word.Application
newApp.Visible=True
Dim newDoc = newApp.Documents.Add
```

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383) and [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VBAutomateWord-1fcb09c6) for some good starting points.

I also refer you to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509702/111794) (It's for python, but the principles are the same).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  the misspelled word and implementing the library is was did.  I can now successfully open a document.  Now on to my search and replace functions... :)